# How can I use an array in a different Windows form correctly in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, windows, forms, class

I gotta ask for some data and then I need to save all those stuff in an array. I created a class to save all the arrays I need but when I try to save the variables in my array it looks like I need to call a local variable. So, how can I save different variables in an array that I declared in a different class?

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Terminal terminales = new Terminal();
        String terminalName = textName.Text;
        terminales.TerminalName = terminalName;
        

        String terminalDirection = directText.Text;
        terminales.TerminalDirection = terminalDirection;

        String terminalPhone = phoneText.Text;
        terminales.TerminalPhone = terminalPhone;


        DateTime horaApertura = DateTime.Parse(hour1Text.Text.ToString());
        //return horaApertura.Value.ToString("HH:mm");
        terminales.HoraApertura = horaApertura;
        DateTime horaCierre = DateTime.Parse(hour1Text.Text.ToString());
        terminales.HoraCierre = horaCierre;

        contador = contador + 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < Arreglos.terminalesArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Arreglos.terminalesArray[i] != null)
            {
                Arreglos.terminalesArray[i] = terminales;
                break;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show(terminales.HoraCierre.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(Arreglos.terminalesArray[0].HoraApertura.ToString());
    }
```

The message boxes were just for testing.```
This is the class coding:

```
public class Terminal
    {
        private int terminalID;
        private string terminalName;
        private string terminalDirection;
        private string terminalPhone;
        private bool terminalEstado;
        private DateTime horaApertura;
        private DateTime horaCierre;

        public Terminal()
        {



        }
        public Terminal(int terminalID,
                          string terminalName,
                          string terminalDirection,
                          string terminalPhone,
                          bool terminalEstado,
                          DateTime horaApertura,
                          DateTime horaCierre)
        {
            this.terminalID = terminalID;
            this.terminalName = terminalName;
            this.terminalDirection = terminalDirection;
            this.terminalPhone = terminalPhone;
            this.terminalEstado = terminalEstado;
            this.horaApertura = horaApertura;
            this.horaCierre = horaCierre;
        }

        public int TerminalID { get => terminalID; set => terminalID = value; }
        public string TerminalName { get => terminalName; set => terminalName = value; }
        public string TerminalDirection { get => terminalDirection; set => terminalDirection = value; }
        public string TerminalPhone { get => terminalPhone; set => terminalPhone = value; }
        public bool TerminalEstado { get => terminalEstado; set => terminalEstado = value; }
        public DateTime HoraApertura { get => horaApertura; set => horaApertura = value; }
        public DateTime HoraCierre { get => horaCierre; set => horaCierre = value; }
    }
```

Comment: There's no need to do `.Text.ToString()` as `.Text` is already the `string`.

Comment: It's like the code you've posted in your question has nothing to do with the description of your problem. The closest thing that matches is the `Arreglos.terminalesArray`, but you haven't posted that code. Can you please ensure you're showing us the complete code and show us how your code applies to "save different variables in an array that I declared in a different class"?

Comment: It's cause the program is based in Forms. I posted just the two parts that I thought could be the problem here

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't clear anything up. Can you explain more?

Comment: I gotta ask for some data from the user with the forms, and then save all that in 5 different string arrays, I've created an object for each that contains all what they need. But it won't save it all, it looks like it can't use my array, even though it's public. Is there any other declaration to make in the method?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the code that you've written that doesn't work. Then we can help fix it. Asking vague questions in the comments is not the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

“static”, is probably the answer.  If the class Terminal was made to static.  And it’s variables were made to static.  Then they would be globally visible.  It would only allow one set of values, but I don’t see anything in your code or description that indicates that would be a problem.

Comment: `static` is very rarely the answer.